# CSS hover firing more than once with webkit 3d transform

Tags: css, hover, transform, webkit-transform

When I use a webkit 3d transform on hover, only the top 50% of the hover area works, while the bottom 50% is unstable. I'm currently testing on Chrome (31.0.1650.63). Is it a bug? Is there any workaround?

Try to place your mouse on the top of the div and slowly bring it to the bottom.

**HTML**

```
<div class="hoverArea"></div>
<div class="flip">
    <div class="front">front</div>
    <div class="back">back</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hoverArea, .flip, .front, .back {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.hoverArea {
  z-index: 10;
}
.flip {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -webkit-perspective: 800;
  z-index: 9;
}
.front {
  background-color: #f00;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden ;
}
.back {
  background-color: #f0f;
  -webkit-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden ;
}
.hoverArea:hover + .flip {
  -webkit-transform: rotatex(-180deg);  
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4P53y/

Comment: It seems fine to me, can you be more specific with what the problem is?

Comment: In chrome 32 the bottom half works 100% and the top is buggy.

Comment: Looks fine to me in V.31

Comment: works for me on win8 - 31.0.1650.63

Comment: @JoshPowell when I place the mouse over the top 50% of the div.hoverArea, the 3d effect is nice, but when I move my mouse over the bottom 50% area of the div.hoverArea, it keeps rotating like crazy

Comment: Ahh okay okay I see what you mean.

Comment: @Paulie_D please try to place your mouse on the top of the div and slowly bring it to the bottom. Is it working?

Comment: @Andre Fuentes seems to be. What is the expected behaviour that isn't happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can fix it by removing the `.hoverArea` element and instead apply the `:hover` event on the `.flip` element.

```
.flip:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotatex(-180deg);    
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4P53y/2/)

If you want to still use the `.hoverArea` element then you can use `transform:translateZ(1px);` on `.hoverArea` to make it function correctly. It makes the browser render the element more carefully

```
.hoverArea {
    z-index: 10;
    -webkit-transform:translateZ(1px);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4P53y/3/)

Comment: You're one minute faster than me. Cheers

Comment: Works good, thanks! I thought hovering behavior would mess up if I 3d transformed itself, that's why I used another element for it

Comment: @AndreFuentes Also added an alternative to allow using `.hoverArea` to work in the case that you want it to cover more area than `.flip` does